# undefined method `symbolize_keys' when using factory girl traits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I'm using ruby v1.9.3 and factory_girl v2.2  and trying to setup traits.  But am getting this error when I try to use my trait. Is it because of the ruby version I am using?

```
 Failure/Error: let!(:notification) { create(:notification, :confirmable) }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `symbolize_keys' for :confirmable:Symbol
 # ./spec/controllers/api/v1/sms_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>
```

This is my factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :notification do
    smssid { Faker::Number.number(10) }
    msg    { Faker::Lorem.sentence(3) }
    to     { Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number }

    trait :confirmable do
      confirmable  "true"
    end
  end
end
```

spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Api::V1::SmsController do

  let!(:user) { create(:user) }

  describe "GET /api/v1/user/sms" do

    let!(:notification) { FactoryGirl.create(:notification, :confirmable) }

    context "a user replies to a confirmation with c" do
      it "does something" do
        get :incomming_message, :sid => notification.smssid,
                                :to => notification.to,
                                :from => user.phone_number,
                                :body => "c",
                                :status => "recieved",
                                :format => :json
        notification.reload
        notification.confirmed.should eq(true)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

*** Edit, updated with my spec file

Comment: What does your spec file look like

Comment: For older versions of FactoryGirl I think you use traits differently, e.g., https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/v2.2.0/GETTING_STARTED.md

Comment: I would try to update your app as soon as possible, Ruby 1.9.3 is no longer supported and is insecure. Your issues also seem to be that you are using an outdated version of FactoryGirl with newer docs as @DaveNewton pointed out.

Comment: @DaveNewton I looked through the docs, it seems that the trait is setup correctly.  They don't give any example on using a trait when building a factory though.

Comment: *Which* docs? For which version of FG? AFAIK both the error message and the 2.2 docs indicate you're not using it right for what `create` expects in your version.

Comment: What happens if you do this:

    let!(:notification) { FactoryGirl.create(:notification, 'confirmable') }

or perhaps this:  

    let!(:notification) { FactoryGirl.create(:notification, 'confirmable' => true) }

Comment: I updated my factory to how the docs have the traits setup.  It's works now, but is returning notification as a hash and not a object.  I call the factory like this `create(:confirmable_notification)`

Answer (score -1):

No, the version of Ruby you are using has nothing to do with `symbolize_keys` because it is not part of the the Ruby core.  Neither 1.9.3 nor 2.2.2 contain it. Rather, `symbolize_keys` is an ActiveSupport extension to the Hash class.  You must have Active support loaded to get this to work. See: [Rails-4.2.5 : Object::HashWithIndifferentAccess < Hash](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html).

Since this is a RoR question, which I missed (mea culpa), the problem evidently lies with the declaration of `confirmable` as a symbol rather than a hash.  However, the version of Ruby in use has nothing to do with the problem in either case.

Comment: ... "The problem is with the arguments you're passing in." Right, but the OP is asking *why* it's a problem, not for confirmation that it's a problem.